# UIPATH - dynamic if condition

Tags: contains, rpa, uipath

I' using a "Do Each" loop that provides an "item" of type string for my "IF" condition.

item is one of these strings from this string array :

> {"Test01","Test02","Test03","Test04"}

Folder is one of these string from this new string array :

> {"01 - [Test01 (VR)]","02 - [Test02 (VR)]","03 - [Test03 (VR)]"}

This next condition is not working

> Folder.contains(item)
> This next one is working
> Folder.contains("Test01")

I guess the issue is that, "Contains" only find item if its between space delimiter.

here is a screenshot

[image]

Please let me know if you have some ideas of what happening.

Answer (score 0):

You have the **wrong type** set.

Do the following:

1. Click on the `For Each scope`
2. Go to properties
3. Switch the `TypeArgument` from `Object` to `String` (if `String` does not work try `ArrayOf<String>`)

Bonus: the `.toString` is not needed anymore

Comment: It was a good idea, I edit my code but it's still the same sadly, with string type at least.

Comment: Do some isolated Process where you just create the String Array and the for each and show me again. If you not succeed in it I will create you that process for demonstrating.

Comment: I just found what's wrong thanks to my last test, I will edit my post with some new informations about my string array.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by re build my For each loop with string as type arguments.
it was already like that before but for some reason it work now